# formatting date (saved in DB as datetime)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime

I have a bunch of records in SQL SERVER and i'm having an issue with one of the fields.

The datatype is datetime. The system was only inserting a date with no time in it, so '1/2/2017' - so when it was inserted in SQL SERVER it would show only as 1/2/2017 00:00:00. Now, what I'm trying to do is to display it just as it is saved in the DB.

I query the DB and display it like this...

```
   If Not IsDBNull(dr("ReceivedOn")) Then
       txtReceivedOn.Text = Format(dr("ReceivedOn"), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")
   End If
```

The mask on my masked textbox is liek this.....

```
 00/00/0000 90:00 aa
```

When it does get displayd in the masked textbox is shows the date and 12:00 AM

```
1/2/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

Is there to get rid of it, and only show 0's instead of a incorrect time? However I'd like to only see a 12 hr time rather than 24.

Comment: Did you mean you're trying to change 12:00 AM into 00:00:00?

Comment: Just change the hh in HH

Comment: @ben yes im trying to display 00:00 since 12 AM is incorrect time. This is only for a fewbhundred old records. All new dates are save with correct time

Comment: I believe the tt is causing the AM/PM, perhaps try MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the format specifier for hours from `hh` to `HH`

```
If Not IsDBNull(dr("ReceivedOn")) Then
    txtReceivedOn.Text = Format(dr("ReceivedOn"), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt")
End If
```

On MSDN at the [DateTime Custom Date and Time strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) you can read

> The "HH" custom format specifier (plus any number of additional "H"
>   specifiers) represents the hour as a number from 00 through 23; that
>   is, the hour is represented by a zero-based 24-hour clock that counts
>   the hours since midnight. A single-digit hour is formatted with a
>   leading zero.

Note that, with this format, the `tt` is meaningless.

Comment: it shows 24hr clock - i need it to display 12 hr with AM/PM. The problem i have is if the SQL SERVER shows time as 00:00:00 since only a date was inserted into a datatime field - my masked textbox shows it as 12:00 AM - which I don't want to do. I want it to simply show the Date and 00:00:00. People don't like military/european time. All new records that are inserted have the time stamp so show accurately with hh rather than HH

Comment: Then is just a problem with the MaskedTextBox? You can set the Mask property to 00/00/0000 to support the DatePart but I think that this control cannot display a time part, Let me check something

Comment: Yeah I set the mask to this : 00/00/0000 90:00 aa    - so when I removed the tt and added HH instead of hh it showed it like this 1/2/2017 12:00 __. I removed the mask altogether and still shows the same thing. :(

Comment: I was going to but has to be masked textbox. Okay since these are old records  I'll just make everyone aware to disregard the 12:00AM. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems that there is no way out from this hh format. It displays hours as values from 01 to 12. Perhaps you can try with _Format(dr("ReceivedOn"), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt").Replace(" 12:", " 00:")_

Comment: That could work but as I said all new entries have time stamps so any record entered at 12 would display 00. I appreciate your help